# How to show alert message if pdf file not found in server?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

i have done application using Extjs, here requirement is need to download file from server also need to showcase loadmask untill file is completely download. Here i am generating dynamic pdf url by appending name to server base URL. some time in server don't have pdf file for particular url(name) may be they will add or delete the pdf files for some names, but i am assigning generated pdf url based on selected name to ifrmae as a source path. **if the pdf is not found in server that time iframe is shows a page, like 404 server not found etc..**. instead of this one i need to showcase alert message pdf file is not available for this particular name. Can anybody tell me How to achieve this one? great appreciated. Thank you.

**Here is my code:**

```
getPdfDataIniFrame: function(vesselName){
        var strVesselName=vesselName;
        vesselSpecificationName=strVesselName.replace(" ","_");
        speficationUrl="http://BaseUrl/"+vesselSpecificationName+".pdf"  
Ext.getCmp('pnlPdf').update('<iframe id="iframeId" width="100%" height="85%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="'+speficationUrl+'"></iframe>')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cant you try with ajax implementation. i feel the plm may be bind of request with iframe and update to component. try with below one. it may help!!

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: <url>,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json', 
        'Accept': 'application/pdf'
    },
    success: function(response){

    },
    failure: function(response){

    }
});
```

`Accept: application/pdf` is most important.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have tried as above but it is giving error in console like this. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://BaseUrlofServer/Sea_Kiowa.pdf. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. How to resolve this issue? Thank you

Comment: check response header in browser debug tool (Developer tool or firebug).

Comment: I am getting..from failed response like this. getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function () {
getResponseHeader: function (header) {
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function () {
request: Object
async: true
headers: Object
id: 1
options: Object
__proto__: Object
requestId: 1
responseText: ""
responseXML: null
status: 0
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object